# Jump to 2 positions before at the end of a key mapping definition

Tags: vim

I am trying to modify a vim configuration file in order to copy all into system clipboard. The problem is that with the following code the cursor is moved to first line and I want to go back to the position I was before running it.

```
" copy all to the clipboard
nnoremap <Leader>a ggVG"+y
```

I have looked at the documentation, concretely in `:help :jumps` but I do not know how change previous the previous code to do a jump to the position 2 in the jump list in order to be put in the same line I was when I run it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### Maintaining the cursor position

You can just tack on a [`CTRL-O`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/motion.txt.html#CTRL-O) command (as `<C-o>`) to your mapping (which supports a `[count]`), or for the last jump position just use ``` `` ```, as @Kent has answered.

#### Maintaing the view

These jumps will keep your cursor position, but may still affect what's currently displayed inside the window (a.k.a. the *view*), as jumps just ensure that the target is visible. Fortunately, Vim has functions to save and restore the full view: [`winsaveview()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#winsaveview%28%29) and [`winrestview()`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/eval.txt.html#winrestview%28%29). Unfortunately, they are cumbersome to use in a simple mapping (as you need a variable to store the view).

The [anwolib plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=3800) provides a handy `:KeepView {cmd}` command that makes this way easier:

```
nnoremap <Leader>a :KeepView normal! ggVG"+y<CR>
```

#### Yank alternatives

You don't actually need to use a visual selection for this; the [`:yank`](https://vimhelp.appspot.com/change.txt.html#%3Ayank) Ex command is a handy alternative. Luckily (for your requirement), it doesn't change the cursor position at all, so you just need this:

```
nnoremap <Leader>a :%yank +<CR>
```

Answer (score 1):

give this a try:

```
nnoremap <Leader>a ggVG"+y``
```

Comment: It seems it does not work because it only jumps once